# Rails on Apache on Windows - HOWTO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, apache

This question has not been asked since Rail 3.0 came out (or I cannot find it):

How to run Rails 3+ application on Apache on Windows (WAMP)? Is Mongrel the best option? Sounds not optimal to me to have Apache as a proxy and then another server. Passenger does not exist on Windows.

What I hope to get from your is a link to a magical installation package and a snippet from the httpd.conf file that would divert one  to a rails application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of using apache (or nginx) as a proxy is that it can load-balance between different mongrel (or thin) instances. So you would have to start three mongrel instances (services) and configure apache to proxy those.

Configuring apache to different mongrel processes is pretty straightforward, can be found all over the internet. Here is an example of a `httpd-vhosts.conf` (replace `yourapplication` by your actual application/domain and root-folder):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerName 10.200.65.35
    #ServerAlias 10.200.65.35
    ServerName yourapplication.com

    DocumentRoot d:/yourapplication/current/

    <Directory c:/yourapplication/current/public/ >
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>


     # On active les proxy qui sont par défaut désactivés
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Proxy balancer://mongrel_cluster>
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:4000
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:4001
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:4002
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / Balancer://mongrel_cluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mongrel_cluster/
    #ProxyReserveHost on


    #log files
    ErrorLog "/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/yourapplication_error.log"
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog "/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/yourapplication_access.log" combined

    #Rewrite stuff
    RewriteEngine On

    # Rewrite index to check for static
    RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [QSA] 

    # Rewrite to check for Rails cached page
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]

    # Redirect all non-static requests to cluster
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://mongrel_cluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Another, very promising alternative to deploy on windows is using [TorqueBox](http://torquebox.org/).
TorqueBox is JBoss/Jruby based solution, and thus platform independent. In [benchmarks](http://torquebox.org/news/tags/benchmarks/) it is shown that TorqueBox performs incredibly well, and actually anybody should seriously consider switching to it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about InstantRails have you tried it? http://rubyforge.org/projects/instantrails/

> Instant Rails is a one-stop Rails runtime solution containing Ruby, Rails, Apache, and MySQL, all pre-configured and ready to run. No installer, you simply drop it into the directory of your choice and run it. It does not modify your system environment.

What about trying a virtual machine like Vagrant: http://vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/index.html

Or perhaps JRubyStack.

As far as I know, the only way to deploy rails in windows is using apache + mongrel. Good luck!

Comment: The link to instantrails you provide is extremely old, I would advise anybody to stay far away from that now.

Comment: I agree with @nathanvda. I was aware of InstantRails, but forgot to mention that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is  very old question, but I've just found a very easy solution which doesn't involve installing any new software. It only requires a few more flags in httpd.conf. It's detailed in this article on editrocket.com:

http://editrocket.com/articles/ruby_apache_windows.html