# Apache module for Ruby on Rails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, apache

I have a none standard need:  I am going to develop an application that is part desktop app, part web app, but both are running on my customers machines.  So there will be an install that will install everything, including the web server(s) on the customers machine.  One requirement is that this system target both Windows and OSX users.  I have three viable options:  Java, PHP, or Ruby on Rails.  My preference is Ruby on Rails, but I need to find an Apache module that will work with Windows.  Is there such a beast?  If not, how do folks run Ruby on Rails on Windows under Apache?

I am fully aware of the fact that Ruby on Rails does not need Apache, but the application will need Apache to fulfill all it's requirements.  Thus the preference would be for an Apache module.  If that isn't possible, I am open to other options.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890226/should-i-give-up-on-deploying-rails-under-windows might give you somewhere to start

Comment: Just curiose. What requirements need to be fulfilled to make a decision to use apache on each customer computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you really want to go that route, you could probably use `mod_rails` or `mod_fcgi`. It might be an easier route to use a rails-specific webserver like Thin or Mongrel and just attach Apache as a frontend like it's usually done for load balancing.

See here for more inspiration:

[Rails on Apache on Windows - HOWTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095070/rails-on-apache-on-windows-howto)

However, Ruby on Rails is a pain on Windows even with the nice RubyInstaller packages. I've tried to work in this environment but you will quickly run into problems with gems not compiling or generally incompatible with Windows. Still, there's folks who stick to it.

Again, related posts on SO, which already covered this topic:

[Limitations in running Ruby/Rails on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164896/limitations-in-running-ruby-rails-on-windows?rq=1)

[Is there anyway to run Ruby on Rails applications on a Windows box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35494/is-there-anyway-to-run-ruby-on-rails-applications-on-a-windows-box?rq=1)